# How to enable type annotations in VS Code for a single variable

Tags: visual-studio-code, annotations

As I understood correctly VS Code already has support for type annotations in TypeScript and JavaScript, but how do I enable it or use it properly for inline variables where VS Code does not understand the referer correctly?

Here is my code:

```js
export const TooltipModule = {
  init() {
    this.tooltipElements = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip')
    if (this.tooltipElements.length > 0) {
      this.enableTooltips()
    }
  },

  enableTooltips() {
    /** @var {Element} tp */
    for (const tp of this.tooltipElements) {
      new Tooltip(tp /* no type annotation here */, {
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Top',
      })
    }
  },
}
```

[image]

I have also tried using `@type` or `@param`.